# How to assign array to a parameter with rosrun?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

footprint: [[0.4, 0.0], [-0.16, -0.22], [-0.18, 0.35]]

If I want to add this footprint parameter with rosrun like below:
rosrun move_base move_base __name:=move_base_node _local_costmap/footprint:=[[0.4,0.0],[-0.16,-0.22],[-0.18,0.35]]

footprint becomes a string.

What is the right syntax to assign integer array in footprint parameter?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58838/how-to-assign-array-to-a-parameter-with-rosrun?/) by [Tareq Haque](https://answers.ros.org/users/4491/tareq-haque/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-03-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You use standard [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) syntax for rosrun [paramter assignment](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments).

That being said, I was able to reproduce the behavior you're seeing, and also got some interesting results.  Perhaps this is a bug in rosrun?  See below:

```
rosrun rospy_tutorials talker __name:=talker _test:=[0,1,2]
rosparam get /talker/test
    [0, 1, 2]

rosrun roscpp_tutorials talker __name:=talker _test:=[0,1,2]
rosparam get /talker/test
    '[0,1,2]'
```

It appears as if parameters are correctly YAML-parsed when using rosrun with a **python** node, but not with a **cpp** node.  I tried all sorts of different variations on the YAML bit.  Using a scalar number works, but all other more-complex YAML constructs (sequences, maps, etc.) all seem to parse as plain strings.

Does anyone have a correct formulation, or is this really a rosrun bug?  I was able to reproduce the same behavior in both groovy and fuerte (current debian packages).

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3